# Посчитать сумму элементов вектора, расположенных после минимального элемента

Tags: вектор

Нужно посчитать сумму элементов вектора, расположенных после минимального элемента. Сумму элементов вектора посчитать могу, но как прикрутить минимальный элемент не соображу.Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идёте по элементам, подсчитывая сумму.

Если встретили элемент меньше *(или `<=`  -  в вопросе не уточняется ситуация с несколькими равными мин. элементами)* текущего минимума - обнуляете сумму

Можно также найти позицию минимума, потом вычислить сумму элементов, начиная со следующей позиции